# If the mouse over check

Tags: jquery

I want to check mouseover and mouse leave status and execute some function if the mouse is over element or is out.
I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
if($('#someid').is(':hover')){ DO STUFF OVER }else{ DO STUFF ELSE }
```

Comment: Is `#someid` actually `:hover`ed when you're checking the state? It seems obvious that it isn't. Can you provide a page demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#someid').hover(
    function(){
        // do stuff when mouseover
    },
    function(){
        // do stuff on mouseout.
    });
```

Reference:

- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#someid').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    // do stuff when mouse is over an elemet
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
    // do stuff when mouse left the elemet
});
```

See [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [events](http://api.jquery.com/category/Events/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=API/1.3/Events&redirect=no).

Answer (score 1):

write this

```
$('#someid').hover(
function(){
     DO STUFF OVER 
},
function(){
    DO STUFF ELSE 
}
);
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.hover` function which is shorthand for `.mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Here's an example, and here's a [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/):

```
​$('#a').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');  
});​​​​​​​
```